# How to convert SSRS 2008 Server reports to SSRS 2008 Client Reports

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a large SSRS 2008 Server Report Project (more than 200 reports). Currently my company strategy has been changed and we want to convert these server reports to client reports.

All of the Server reports use stored procedures (or in some cases from the SQL functions)

All of them work properly andthere is no problem

Beause of project scale it is not a good idea to create all of server reports in client again.

So I want to check how to convert SSRS 2008 Server reports to SSRS 2008 Client reports (`.rdl` to `.rdlc`).

Note : I know that client reports use Dataset and I have to create Dataset. I'm also looking for a way to generate these dataset too. But for now I'm just looking for a way to convert `.RDL` files to `.RDLC` files.

If there are any application which can convert RDL XML to RDLC XML let me know.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a while I foud this [Converting RDL and RDLC Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109(VS.80).aspx) helpfull

Answer (score 2):

1- Rename the .rdl file to use the .rdlc file extension.

2- In Visual Studio 2008, open the solution or project that will contain the report.

3- Create or add the dataset that defines the data you want to use to your projector solution. For more information, see Creating Data Sources for a Report.

4- On the Project menu, click Add Existing Item and then select the .rdlc file that you created in the first step.

5- In the project, open the form or Web page that will contain the report.

Comment: @Masoud, I know these steps, and I'm looking for a way to doall these work in one step. Like Dataset Generator or etc

Comment: @nasser: you cannot find anything Like this.

Comment: in renaming RDL to RDLC - is there any consideration or not ?

Comment: @nasser: if name of fields in your dataset have been changed, you must change the value of your controls manually.